# Activity Display but controls with be enabled after 5 seconds In android

Tags: android

I am displaying one activity in this one image view is there and only image is display to the user. user will not allow to do any task such as like or comment.
the screen will on 5 seconds hold.
after that controls on that screen will be enabled and workable
even user does not allow to go back from the screen till the 5 seconds will not be completed.
how do i implement this functionality

I have written the code

```
public class AdvertActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ImageView ivEAdvertUserImage,ivEAdvertImage;
TextView  tvEAdvertDislike,tvEAdvertLike,tvEAdvertHeading;
EditText etEAdvertComments;
Button btnEAdvertSubmit;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_advert);
    InitUI();
    tvEAdvertLike.setOnClickListener(this);
    tvEAdvertDislike.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnEAdvertSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.tvEAdvertLike:
        tvEAdvertLike.setTextColor(color.Blue);
        break;
    case R.id.tvEAdvertDislike:
        tvEAdvertDislike.setTextColor(color.Blue);
        etEAdvertComments.setEnabled(true);
        btnEAdvertSubmit.setEnabled(true);
        break;
    case R.id.btnEAdvertSubmit:
        Intent in =new Intent(AdvertActivity.this,EAdFragment.class);
        startActivity(in);
        finish();
        break;
    default:

        break;
    }
}


public void InitUI(){
    ivEAdvertUserImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivEAdvertUserImage);
    ivEAdvertImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivEAdvertImage);
    etEAdvertComments=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEAdvertComments);
    tvEAdvertDislike=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEAdvertDislike);
    tvEAdvertLike=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEAdvertLike);
    tvEAdvertHeading=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvEAdvertHeading);
    btnEAdvertSubmit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEAdvertSubmit);
}



}
```

Comment: Why dont you just use Handler.postDelayed(Runnable, time in millis) or Timer Task? I think that is the easiest way to solve your problem.

Comment: Are you familiar with `Timer` ? Tried anything?

Comment: Mention not. Always ready to help everyone ! !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_advert);
    InitUI();

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            //  Will be called after 5000ms
            tvEAdvertLike.setOnClickListener(this);
            tvEAdvertDislike.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnEAdvertSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

This way your Listeners will be set after 5 seconds. Before that, the buttons etc. will have no effect if someone clicks them.

(Can not test my code right now, but it should work)

Comment: No problem. Please accept my answer (little checkmark on the left) if it solved your problem.